# How can I trigger custom emails to be sent in wordpress?

Tags: email, triggers, newsletter

My goal is to use a user's answers to a few questions to trigger custom emails being sent to them with filtered content on my wordpress website. It seems like this is a common need, but can't find anything that allows it, or even is the right base to build a custom solution.

There are 3 main features I'm needing to do:  First, the signup form lets users choose a few criteria via selection boxes.

Next, the captured information triggers an email being sent that matches the content they chose.  For example, if the user says they're interested in waterskiing, the email that is auto sent would show the most recent posts in the water-skiing category.

Finally, the user responses would need to be saved to trigger actions at a later time if the content is not available yet. So for example, if they are interested in bowling, but there are no entries on bowling, nothing happens.  However, once a post gets entered in this category, they are automatically emailed with that recent entry.

Any clarity you can provide here on plugins, software, etc that would lend to this functionality is much appreciated!!